# How to replace values in a column in a fast and memory efficient manner

Tags: python, memory-management

I have a `dataframe` containing 114 Million records with 2 columns named `session_id` and `artifact_id`. Both the columns are categorical. I would like to replace the values in the column `artifact_id` with the values in a dictionary where each value in `artifact_id` is mapped to another value. `Artifact_id` is an `int` column and the values to be replaced are also `int` values. There are about 322k unique values that are to be replaced.

Here's my sample dataset:

```
Session_id    artifact_id
    A              234
    A              123
    B              123
    B              678
```

The contents of the dictionary are as follows:

```
{'234':'1','123':'2','678':'3'}
```

I would like the final dataset to look like this:

```
Session_id    artifact_id
    A              1
    A              2
    B              2
    B              3
```

I would have thought that the following statement would replace these values:

```
Sessions['artifact_id'].replace(artifactId2Num, inplace=True)
```

`artifactId2Num` is the name of the dictionary. This statement gives me an `out of memory` error. So I thought about breaking the process up into various pieces to avoid `MemoryError` using the following code:

```
count = 0
for idx in xrange(0,len(Sessions),50000):
    count = count + 1
    print(count)
    if (idx+50000) > len(Sessions):
        Sessions[idx:(len(Sessions)-1)]['artifact_id'].replace(artifactId2Num, inplace=True)
    else:
        Sessions[idx:(idx+50000)]['artifact_id'].replace(artifactId2Num, inplace=True)
```

The above code runs so far without any errors. It has been running for about 10+ hours and hasn't finished yet.

**MORE INFO:** The original dataframe with 114 Million records fits well in the memory and takes about 4.2 GB. The moment I run the above code with iterations, the memory occupancy suddenly increases to almost 20GB. **I'm clearly working on only 50000 records at a time and replacing values from the dictionary. Why would the memory usage increase drastically?**

Is there a way to make this code faster? Or is there another way I can achieve the same result?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: as I understand, is only 322k (of 114 Million) rows where you have to apply the conversion??

Comment: @alvarez: No. There are 322k unique values in 114 Million records that are to be replaced. So the values are getting repeated.

Comment: ok, this changes the perspective.

Comment: I added more details to the question to provide a sample dataset and the values it needs to be replaced with.

Comment: @roganjosh: Great catch, you're right. I messed it up over here, but it's fine in the code. I'll fix it right now.

Comment: Makes more sense :) ok, does the actual DF fit happily in memory then prior to trying to do this?

Comment: @roganjosh: Yes, it does. It takes a little over 4GB in memory.

Comment: I can't test anything my end atm but I wouldn't expect it to take over 10 hours. What happens if you take `the_list = Sessions.artifact_id.values.to_list()`, slice that list for say the first 100,000 entries and do `new_column = [my_dict[item] if my_dict.get(item) else item for item in the_list]`? I'm curious where the overhead comes from.

Comment: @roganjosh: Your solution worked like a charm and in under a minute. Thanks a lot :). If you could post an answer, I will accept it in no time. The only correction is to use `tolist()` instead of `to_list()`

Comment: Ah, but I hate my solution, there should be no reason to pull it out of the dataframe. I was just interested in setting a benchmark. I suspect your approuch makes tonnes of copies, hopefully you can get a pandas approach as an answer. Also, my approach might be faster with `my_dict.get (item, item)` and get rid of if/else

Comment: @roganjosh I was about to comment on this one - if replace calls another 2-3 functions, each making a nice copy of the data that would explain 4 GB to ~20 GB jump. Your solution is useful!

Comment: Oooh, you have a `print` in your loop! As an aside, this will add _loads_ of overhead in your approach. It doesn't change memory but keep this in mind. `if count % 10000 == 0: print count` will speed things up significantly. If nobody has given a pandas answer in a few hours, I will write my approach as an answer. Doing so will discourage others from opening question though, and you have something workable in the meantime so no rush.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
d = {'123': '2', '234': '1', '678': '3'}
df['artifact_id'] = df.artifact_id.astype(str).map(d)
```